# Replace periods with a space in a file using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to parse through a file and find every period there is and replace it with a space instead. I've started writing the code, but I'm fairly new to bat files and I'm not sure how to figure out what's wrong.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ('delete.bat "/o:," ^D:\Docs\test.csv') do (
set str =%%b
set str1=!str1:.= !
)
```

When this runs I want it to remove the periods, but I'm receiving an error that says delete.bat does not exist.

I want it to see a csv with an input like: "Hi. How are you." And just change it to "Hi How are you"

Comment: 1) What does delete.bat do? Not sure why you would need it. You only need the `FOR /F` to read the CSV file. 2) Remove the space before the equals sign in your first set command. 3) Your second set command is using `STR1` for the variable.  You never assign any value to that variable. 4) You are referencing the variable with delayed expansion but you have not enabled delayed expansion with the `SETLOCAL` command.

Comment: setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (D:\Docs\test.csv') do (
set str1=%%b
set str1=!str1:.= !
)

the delete.bat file was the name of the file I was running, I saw on a different post they used it, but I wasn't sure what it was for. I'm unable to test this now, but I've made changes to the code based on your comment. Thank you!

Comment: I am 100% positive that your `delete.bat` is really Dave Benham's [ParseCSV.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702). Why you are attempting to obfuscate its use makes no sense to me. Edit your question with your updated code if you are still have problems. Comments are really for small code examples.

Comment: @roshri, please review [MCVE] and [Ask], then edit your original post.